How do I keep Discord Bot online on repl.it?
Previously I used to take the web-url provided and use uptimerobot to ping it at regular intervals but it seems like replit has changed all fo it. The file just keeps stopping everytime u close the site even if u have keep_alive running it.
Due to the changes in the url and the repl being shut down as soon as u close the site, the old method has topped working.
Is there any other way now to solve this?

repl.it is not meant to deploy services or lung-running tasks, but for short, interactive sessions.
If you want to run a service you should deploy it on a provider like AWS or DigitalOcean.

As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers in the help center.

I don't even mean to deploy it full scale. It was just a personal mini project which used to run on replit like I mentioned. I just asked if there was some alternative to it? The way is used to work.
